# spinner error Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class

Tags: android, spinner

I want to attach spinner with my activity but as soon drop spinner code on xml It gives me this error? I do not write any code on activity side just drop spinner xml on layout It show error

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#fff">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<Spinner
    style="@style/width_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></Spinner> 
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: Show us some code to help you solve this error

Comment: show full code with activity and xml

Comment: As soon I try to attach spinner with my xml It show this error.....even just with height and width

Comment: Show your Activity code and the whole layout

Comment: I do not write any code on activity side....just put spinner on xml side

Comment: put below 2 lines in spinner and then clean and build your project,

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: It still giving me same error.....Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class <unknown>

Answer (score 0):

have you created an array for spinner values??
for example:

```
 <string-array name="country_arrays">
    <item>Malaysia</item>
    <item>United States</item>
    <item>Indonesia</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>Singapore</item>
    <item>New Zealand</item>
    <item>India</item>
</string-array>
```

In spinner, you can add the attribute **entries**

```
<Spinner
    style="@style/width_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
>
</Spinner>
```

Comment: Yes I have created string array also but same error

Answer (score 0):

Yoru Spinner is not inside a parent root layout such as the RelativeLayout you define.

The Spinner needs to be inside the layout you are inflating, see below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textColor="#3F51B5"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

 <Spinner
     style="@style/width_height"
     android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></Spinner> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My root layout is LinearLayout and spinner is added in the root layout ....so I think this is not a problem

Comment: Then post your entire layout instead of keeping us guessing.